# Does java webstart always use the latest java version installed on your computer?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have several versions of Java installed:

[image]

I would like to tell Java webstart to use a specific version, but I can't find where to make this config change.

[image]

Does anyone know if it always just uses the latest version on your computer (mine is using 1.8.0_45)? Or even better, does anyone know how to change what version it uses?

Thanks!

Comment: /usr/libexec/java_home command on OS X gives the current java version used by you OS X.

Comment: That's the thing... I can easily set my OS X to pick up another version of Java, but webstart does not follow. My question is specifically how to make webstart use a exact version....

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
<resources>
    <java version="1.7*"/>
```

under resources section in the jnpl file to specify a jvm.

[Source](http://www.basis.com/kb-restrict-java-web-start-clients-specific-jvm-versions)

Comment: I do have that, but what I need is to be able to use a specific version only on my machine (for example for testing). So the jnlp specifies 1.8*, but on my machine I want it to use 1.8.0_40 specifically, let's say.

Comment: You can try /path/to/your/javaws /path/to/jnlp ? I known seems wrong but it should work.